# Android TCP sockets Service and sleep mode

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I have a service, always running, which is my TCP server, listening for incoming connections. The fact is that when I push the power button, the phone goes in sleep mode, and I can't reach the phone from another device, while immediately after i wake up the phone, all starts to work again. I guess i have to use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, isn't it? Or there's another solution?

EDIT: I'm on WIFI for the moment, later I'll switch to WIFI-DIRECT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I guess i have to use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, isn't it?`

Correct. If you permit device to goes into sleep, no code will be run and therefore your TCP server will not be able to accept connections.

Regards.